# R Studio: work on PDF file or HTML file to extract informations

Tags: r, rstudio, financial

I'm looking for a way to work on a PDF file (or using a direct link).

I have to work on file PDF file to extract information about a companies financial statements and I desire to work on the file directly. Is it possible? Have i to transform the pdf into text file? After, is it possible to search specific information on that file?

I'm asking if all this stuff is possible and the ways to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a package called pdftools to work with pdf. But you need to parse it to JSON. There is small tutorial in:
http://ropensci.org/blog/2016/03/01/pdftools-and-jeroen